# Retrieve frame from cv2.VideoCapture in C# variable type

Tags: python, .net, opencv, python.net

I'm trying to get frames from a IP camera using `cv2.VideoCapture` function of Python OpenCV. I'm using PythonNet to retrieve this frames to a C# Console Application. But I can't retrieve the boolean and the image that return `cv2.VideoCapture` in C# variables. Anyone knows how do it?

```
dynamic cap = cv2.VideoCapture("camerastream");
dynamic frame1 = cap.read;
```

So, I already know that `frame1` have the output of `cv2.VideoCapture`, that is a boolean and a numpy array. And that `frame1` is a Python object type. But I don't know how to retrieve the boolean and the array from `frame1`.

Comment: if you are using C#, why not just use EMGU CV which is C# wrapper http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial After using this, the data will be in C# variables like Image<Gray, Byte> or bitmap

Comment: Thank you but I already know Emgu. I want to use Python and their scientific libraries. I must to use C# by compatibility with old software of the company ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Solved! This is working.

```
bool retrieved;
dynamic image = np.ndarray;
dynamic cap = cv2.VideoCapture("camerastream");
dynamic frame1 = cap.read();
retrieved = frame1[0];
image = frame1[1];
```

I had forgotten the () in the function ... :-D